# Binary Tetris in tweets

Tags: code-challenge, game

There was recently (a few years back) some buzz on [programming](http://www.i-programmer.info/news/167-javascript/3799-tetris-in-140-bytes.html) [websites](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/12/02/19/1351213/tetris-in-140-bytes) about an implementation of [Tetris in 140 Bytes](https://gist.github.com/1672254#file_annotated.js).
...

It turns out that although it is small, it is a simplified version of Tetris, and not even a complete implementation. Only the core logic function fits in 140 bytes of Javascript. To actually run it, you need another ~840 characters of HTML.

We can do better!
This challenge is to implement a complete version of "Binary Tetris" in as few tweets as possible.

**Binary Tetris Rules:**

- The program must display a playing field containing at least 5 columns and 6 rows of cells.

  - Any method of display may be used, as long as the blocks and the edges of the field are clearly marked.
- There must be at least two types of blocks:  `#` and `##`. Additional block support such as `###` or angle blocks shaped like an L will get upvoted by me :P and the most complete game of binary tetris (the most blocks like the original and rotation features) will win my happiness and a possible bounty up 50 rep.
- New blocks are added to the field in the top row, and one block cell must occupy the center column.
- Blocks descend towards the bottom row at a fixed rate.  Blocks must descend even without user input.
- When blocks touch the bottom of the field or a lower block, they stop falling and are fixed in place.  A new block is added.
- When all the columns in the row are filled with blocks, the row is emptied, and all the fixed blocks above drop down one row.
- The program must respond to keypresses.  There must be 3 unique keys that perform the following functions

  - shift current block left 1 column
  - shift current block right 1 column
  - shift current block down 1 row
- Each tweet may only have 140 characters. Using multi-byte characters that can be put in tweets is allowed.
- The rules for what can be in a tweet is simple. If you can tweet it you can use it.
- Interpreted languages follow the same rules. Each section must follow the specs. As long as no run time errors occur (and the rest is valid following the specs) your answer is valid
  **Golfing Rules:**
  Because the original implementation was "tweetable", this challenge requires the same.  Entries must be able to be transmitted as a series of tweets (lines of 140 characters or less).
- The first tweet must contain the name of the compiler/interpreter, the name of the program, and any command line arguments

  - it will be saved as file "P0"
- The following N tweets must contain the program as a series of lines.

  - Each tweet will be stored in a file with the name T<n>, where n is 1..N
- Each line will be added to the previous lines and compiled or interpreted.  It must produce a valid object file or program.
- The program does not need to be functional until the last line is added.
- The program will be run in the following manner *(pseudo-bash)*

  ```
  interp,prog,args = split P0 /\s/ 
  touch $prog
  for file in ./T* do
    cat $prog file > $prog
    $interp $prog $args
    die("FAIL") if $? #detect error
  done
  ```

  The interpreter must be a commonly available executable program that does not already implement Tetris.

**Scoring**:
Fewest Tweets, including P0.  Ties broken by largest number of spare characters (140 * num tweets - total character count).

**Example Entries**

```
chrome a.htm
<html><div id="output"></div></html>
<script>cool java script here</script>
```

Score = 3 (334 spare)

```
cc a.c ;a.out
main(){/*cool prog here*/}
```

Score = 2 (241 spare)

```
tetris
```

Score = 1 (134 spare)    *if it were legal, which it's not*

## Special thanks

I was allowed to post this by Ashelly's consent [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/487?noredirect=1#comment42067_487)

Comment: Tweets may contain UTF-8 characters. Is that true here as well (for example, can we stuff 400ish bytes into a single tweet using CJK characters?)

Comment: @RobertFraser if you can type it into a tweet and send it then yes

Comment: If anything that can fit in a tweet is game, can we have newlines within each of our "tweets?" Line breaks are allowed within tweets.

Comment: @notjagan yes. It you can tweet it you can have it

Comment: If the challenge is going to be that way, you need to include an exact specification of which character sequences are allowed in a tweet.

Comment: With JavaScript, can the output be written with ```console.clear(), console.log(...)``` , or must it be injected into HTML as per the 1st example?

Comment: @Bumpy if it works it can be done like that

Comment: "Each line will be added to the previous lines and compiled or interpreted. It must produce a valid object file or program." - What exactly does that mean for interpreted languages? That it doesn't throw a syntax error, or that it throws no exception at all?

Comment: @JanDvorak running correctly. You get tetris when run and can play it

Comment: Does that rule only apply to the final program then, not the partial ones? You can't expect the partial programs to be playable... (plus, your clarification contradicts the following rule)

Comment: @JanDvorak only the final program

Comment: So... is there _no_ requirement for the partial programs? Is it just code golf except the score is rounded up to a multiple of 140?

Comment: @JanDvorak pretty much. It changes the dynamic a bit. "The program does not need to be functional until the last line is added."

Comment: Please edit to clarify that... your rule suggests that the partial programs have to compile. It looks like you're trying to deceive us ... and both answerers so far fell for it...

Comment: If there is no requirement for the partial programs, why mention them at all? Also, your bash code has that magical `#detect error` formula that suggest you do care about partial programs...

Comment: @JanDvorak I changed my mind. I fixed it :P didn't mean to do that.

Comment: I'm sorry... what did you change your mind from and into? If this just a regular code golf now, you have invalidated both answers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59077/discussion-between-christopher-and-jan-dvorak).

Answer (score 8):

## Python 3, Score of 5 Tweets (242 spare, counting P0)

[image: Demo of Tetris program (smoothed slightly more than posted version)]

<sup>-19 bytes thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)!</sup>

<sup>The spare count does not take into account newlines from between tweets.</sup>

### Tweet 1 (Declaration, 12 bytes)

```
python3 t.py
```

### Tweet 2 (70 bytes)

```py
import msvcrt as m,os;f=c=s=0;a=34636833;r=range;p=1<<32;t=30
while 1:
```

### Tweet 3 (129 bytes)

```py
 if m.kbhit()and b"\xe0"==m.getch():p=[p>>(not(a|f<<1)&p),p,p<<(not(a<<4|f>>1)&p),p>>5-5*(bool(f&p>>5)or p<t)][ord(m.getch())-77]
```

### Tweet 4 (113 bytes)

```py
 c+=1;print("\n".join("".join(".#"[1&(f|p)>>i*5+j]for j in r(5))for i in r(6))[::-1]);os.system("cls")
 if c%t<1:
```

### Tweet 5 (134 bytes)

```py
  if f&p>>5or p<t:s=~s;f|=p;p=2-s<<26
  else:p>>=5
 for i in r(0,t,5):
  if f|31<<i==f:b=bin(f)[2:].zfill(t);f=int(b[:-i-5]+b[t-i:],2)
```

### Full Program (449 bytes)

```py
import msvcrt as m,os;f=c=s=0;a=34636833;r=range;p=1<<32;t=30
while 1:
 if m.kbhit()and b"\xe0"==m.getch():p=[p>>(not(a|f<<1)&p),p,p<<(not(a<<4|f>>1)&p),p>>5-5*(bool(f&p>>5)or p<t)][ord(m.getch())-77]
 c+=1;print("\n".join("".join(".#"[1&(f|p)>>i*5+j]for j in r(5))for i in r(6))[::-1]);os.system("cls")
 if c%t<1:
  if f&p>>5or p<t:s=~s;f|=p;p=2-s<<26
  else:p>>=5
 for i in r(0,t,5):
  if f|31<<i==f:b=bin(f)[2:].zfill(t);f=int(b[:-i-5]+b[t-i:],2)
```

Does some evil bit point hacking and stores the field and piece in two integers. I'll try and post an explanation soon.

Note: This only runs on Windows, but it could be switched to Linux through `msvcrt` → `getch` and `"cls"` → `"clear"`. Additionally, character input doesn't work on Python's IDLE, so I'd recommend running it elsewhere.

Comment: Wow well done! This short

Comment: Good work. `\xe0` is four bytes not one so tweet 3 should be 130. You seem to have missed `time.sleep(.1);c+=1` from tweet 4 and changed the order (I don't know if the order change is intentional) and again `\n` is two bytes not one, so it should be 134.

Comment: ...mind you it seems playable without the `sleep` on my machine.

Comment: You could also test `c%10<1` and remove `c=0`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Thanks for the suggestions! I was in a bit of a hurry when posting this so it seems I was somewhat careless with splitting the tweets.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (4 Tweets / <strike>343</strike> 317 bytes / 243 spare)

Not quite sure about the requirements of the header & Tweets format, so please advise if it needs correcting.  Still a bit more can be shaved off I'm certain.

#### Tweet 1 - P0 (11 bytes)

```
chrome a.js
```

### Tweet 2 (82 bytes)

```
a=y=z=j=0,onkeyup=b=>R((k=b.keyCode-40)?z*2*(d=k+3?k+1?1:.5:2)&65|j*d&a||(z*=d):0)
```

### Tweet 3 (126 bytes)

```
R=d=>{d||(!(!y||a&j>>5)||(y>25?a=0:(31^31&(a|=j)>>y||(a=a>>y+5<<y|a&-1>>>-y-5>>5),y=0)),y-=5),y>=0||(y=30,z=12/(new Date%3+1))
```

### Tweet 4 (98 bytes)

```
j=z<<y;for(o="",i=30;i--;)o+=1<<i&(a|j)?"#":"_",o+=i%5?"":"<br>";O.innerHTML=o},setInterval(R,300)
```

## Run it in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/CookieJon/7Lenhcge/

(Click on the output pane to provide focus for keyboard events)

Comment: Please do not post partially completed or invalid answers to the question.  As per [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7987/definitive-policy-about-answers-not-meeting-the-challenge-specification/7988) this answer should be deleted until it complies with the spec outlined in the question

Comment: @PunPun1000 My apologies.  It's now completed and undeleted.

Comment: No problem, I'll remove my downvote.  Welcome to PPCG.